# How do I save my Person-class to database, and how to use the constructor in php?

Tags: php, oop

I have created a class Person, who contain a person. Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Person {
private $age;
private $firstName;
private $lastName;
private $optional;

function __construct($id) {
    // Load all settings form database, because the person already exists.
}

function __construct($age, $firstName, $lastName, $optional) {
    $this->age = $age;
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
    $this->optional = $optional;
}

function setFirstName($name) {
    $this->firstName = $name;
}

function setLastName($name) {
    $this->lastName = $name;
}

function setOptional($key, $value) {
    $optional[$key] = $value;
}

function setAge($age) {
    $this->age = $age;
}

function getFirstName() {
    return $this->firstName;
}

function getLastName() {
    return $this->lastName;
}

function getOptional($key) {
    return $optional[$key];
}

function getAge() {
    return $this->age;
}
}
?>
```

First: This person will be created if a new user fill a form on the web page (and stored to database) and this person will also be used when the web app want some information about the current user.

How do I interact this class with the database? I guess that I could create two constructors as I have done (I think that you could do like this in java). The first constructor is for when constructing an already registered user, and therefore it will load all information from the database. The second constructor is for when a new user is registered, and it should send all information to the database. Is this the right way to handle the database?

Comment: *“The second constructor is for when a new user is registered, and it should send all information to the database”* You do *not* want to have a constructor with side effects. Instead, have a function or static method that handles creation of a user. That method could then interact with the database, and then construct the `Person` and return it.

Comment: It would be also a good idea to disconnect the functional object than its persistence in the DB. You might want to disconnect the saving from the object instanciation. That's what I would do at least, through a dedicated method saving the object *on demand*

Comment: Can't have 2 constructors in php.  I never tried it before, but sure enough.... "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Foo::__construct() in..."

Comment: @Sebas That make sense, but I do not understand exactly how I would disconnect the saving. Should this class not interact with the database at all? How should I do it then?